# EventListener Click does not working on H tag inside

Tags: javascript

I have this simple Modal that's shows up upon clicking button and a Page inside it, depends of which button is click, 
uno is for page1, dos is for page2 tres is for page3.

the whole box is a button and i have h3 inside it(It's for the title of that button), but when i click the green area which is H3 my pages does not shos up.

I know the problem is that when it clicks h3 it targets the h3 and h3 has ni ID in it.

Can someone help me to make my h3 act as div when i click it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .myBtn {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aqua;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .myBtn h3 {
            background-color:green;
            line-height: 2;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .myBtn:hover {
            background-color: aquamarine;;
        }
        .btns {
            float: left;
        }
        .modal {
            display: none;
            background-color: aqua;
            float: right;
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
        }
        .page1 {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background-color: burlywood;
            margin: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .p1 {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .p2 {
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .p3 {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to Show Modal.</p>
    
    <div class="btns">
        <div class="myBtn" id="uno">
            <h3>uno</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="myBtn " id="dos">
            <h3>dos</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="myBtn "id="tres">
            <h3>tres</h3></div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="modal">
        Modal
        <div class="page1 p1">Page1</div>
        <div class="page1 p2">Page2</div>
        <div class="page1 p3">Page3</div>
    </div>
    
    <!--JS-->
    <script>


        var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
        var getModal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        var getPages = document.querySelectorAll('.page1');
        //console.log(getPages);

      
        for(let i=0; i<btn.length;i++ ){
            btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                hideModal(); 
                getId(); 
                displayPage()}); 
        }

        function hideModal(){
            getModal.style.display = "block";
        }

        function getId(){
            //console.log(event.target.id);
        }

        function hideall(){
            for(let i=0; i<getPages.length;i++ ){
                getPages[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        function displayPage(){
            hideall();
            var btnId = event.target.id;
            console.log(btnId);
            if(btnId == "uno"){
                getPages[0].style.display = "block";
            }else if(btnId == "dos"){
                getPages[1].style.display = "block";
            }else if(btnId == "tres"){
                getPages[2].style.display = "block";
            }
            console.log(getPages[0]);
        }
window.addEventListener('click', closeIfOutside);
function closeIfOutside(e) {
    if(e.target == getModal)
    {
    getModal.style.display = 'none';

    }
}


    </script>
            
</body>
</html>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `pointer-events: none` to your `h3` elements so that any clicks will fall through to the containing parent `div` behind it, allowing you to get the correct id to show the correct page:

```
.myBtn h3 {
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See example below:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
var getModal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var getPages = document.querySelectorAll('.page1');
//console.log(getPages);


for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideModal();
    getId();
    displayPage()
  });
}

function hideModal() {
  getModal.style.display = "block";
}

function getId() {
  //console.log(event.target.id);
}

function hideall() {
  for (let i = 0; i < getPages.length; i++) {
    getPages[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function displayPage() {
  hideall();
  var btnId = event.target.id;
  //console.log(btnId);
  if (btnId == "uno") {
    getPages[0].style.display = "block";
  } else if (btnId == "dos") {
    getPages[1].style.display = "block";
  } else if (btnId == "tres") {
    getPages[2].style.display = "block";
  }
  //console.log(getPages[0]);
}
window.addEventListener('click', closeIfOutside);

function closeIfOutside(e) {
  if (e.target == getModal) {
    getModal.style.display = 'none';

  }
}
```

```css
.myBtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.myBtn h3 {
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.myBtn:hover {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  ;
}

.btns {
  float: left;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  background-color: aqua;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

.page1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.p1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.p2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.p3 {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to Show Modal.</p>

<div class="btns">
  <div class="myBtn" id="uno">
    <h3>uno</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="myBtn " id="dos">
    <h3>dos</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="myBtn " id="tres">
    <h3>tres</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  Modal
  <div class="page1 p1">Page1</div>
  <div class="page1 p2">Page2</div>
  <div class="page1 p3">Page3</div>
</div>
```